# <Model> matching query does not exist

Tags: django, django-models

I've learned python django since three days ago .
I wanted to remove an field from model, so I put the '#' front of that field.
Then I started the server again, but it gave me such an error message
'Userprofile matching query does not exist' (Userprofile is the model which I made.)

How can I solve this problem. I'm just a totally new to django, so even it's not easy to question my problem. If the clue is not enough, please tell me what other information is need.

p.s here is the total error message.

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: h ttp://localhost:8000/

Django Version: 1.6.1
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'admin_tools',
 'admin_tools.theming',
 'admin_tools.menu',
 'admin_tools.dashboard',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'south',
 'autocomplete_light',
 'djcelery',
 'asap_web',
 'facebook',
 'venue',
 'notification',
 'study',
 'general',
 'member',
 'advertise')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in     get_response
  114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args,     **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/jaehoon/PycharmProjects/studysearch/asap_web/__init__.py" in __call__
  89.         return main()
File "/home/jaehoon/PycharmProjects/studysearch/asap_web/__init__.py" in main
  25.             return process_request()
File "/home/jaehoon/PycharmProjects/studysearch/asap_web/__init__.py" in process_request
  53.                     return _call_proper_request_processor()
File "/home/jaehoon/PycharmProjects/studysearch/asap_web/__init__.py" in     _call_proper_request_processor
  77.                     return getattr(self, method_name)(request, *self.args,     **kwargs)
File "/home/jaehoon/PycharmProjects/studysearch/general/views.py" in process_get_request
  19.         if user.is_authenticated() and user.get_profile().is_required_more_info:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py" in get_profile
  441.                                    self._state.db).get(user__id__exact=self.id)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get
  307.                 self.model._meta.object_name)

Exception Type: DoesNotExist at /
Exception Value: UserProfile matching query does not exist.
```

Comment: Share some code please? Or at least an complete error message?

Answer (score 0):

The exception is `DoesNotExist` which is thrown when you use get to retrieve single instance but it does not exist. In your `process_get_request` view:

```
user.get_profile().is_required_more_info
```

is throwing this exception because **there is no profile created for this user**. Note that `user.get_profile()` is deprecated since django 1.5 and you should use OneToOne field or custom user model instead, [from docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.get_profile):

> get_profile() Deprecated in Django 1.5: Deprecated since version 1.5:
>   With the introduction of custom User models, the use of
>   AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE to define a single profile model is no longer
>   supported. See the Django 1.5 release notes for more information.